# Mystery Backup Database Job

Tags: sql-server-2014

I'm running SQL Server 2014. I was checking logs to ensure the automated nightly Backup Database job that was scheduled was completing okay. I noticed another BACKUP DATABASE job had been running nightly. I would like to see if I can disable this job, but I have no idea where it is scheduled. It is not listed in the Jobs folder under SQL Server Agent. The message in the log states "BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 0 pages in 15.770 seconds". When I look at the "physical_device_name" for the jobs I'm aware of it shows the filepath of the backups. The mystery backups just show a long alpha-numeric string in curly brackets. Anybody know what this is? Is it safe to disable? How do I disable?

Answer (score 1):

> The mystery backups just show a long alpha-numeric string in curly brackets. Anybody know what this is?

This might be a [3rd party software](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966520.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) using [Volume Shadow Service (VSS) backup](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2009/04/28/informational-shedding-light-on-vss-vdi-backups-in-sql-server/) .

> I would like to see if I can disable this job, but I have no idea where it is scheduled.

if you are using native TSQL backup, then disable the [SQL Server writer service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175536.aspx) using `services.msc`

you can use sysinternal's process explorer to find out what the process or just ask your windows admin if they are doing snapshot of entire folders or machine.

Related question with some more info : [Can't find process that is creating backups](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115339/cant-find-process-that-is-creating-backups/115341#115341)

Answer (score 1):

This is a VM snapshot or some other third party app taking them.  Rackspace managed backup shows this as well a Veeam snapshots.

If you are using FULL recovery mode, you'll want to have your systems guys set 'do not truncate log' or have them take COPY_ONLY so you don't break your restore chain.